# Petrol engine vs diesel engine

Tags: automotive-engineering

I am a student of mechanical Engineering in Pakistan.I am facing difficulty so I want to know the basic difference between diesel and petrol engine. Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: This sounds like a homework question with no attempt at a solution. Please edit your question to explain what you understand about both and where you are stuck. Otherwise your question is likely to be closed as the answer is readily available on the Internet.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 2):

Basic difference is that petrol engines are spark ignition and diesel engines are compression ignition.

Check out Otto cycle.